# converting ajax response from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8

Tags: php, ajax, character-encoding

I use an Ajax call to receive a response in hebrew. The results come from a different site and are `ISO-8859-1` encoded. My page is `UTF-8`.
the response looks like Cyrillic:

```
îéãò ìî÷áì  áæ÷ äçáøä äéùøàìéú  àéï
```

when I try to use the header on the ajax page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

I get this result:

```
Ã®Ã©Ã£Ã² Ã¬Ã®Ã·Ã¡Ã¬  Ã¡Ã¦Ã· Ã¤Ã§Ã¡Ã¸Ã¤ Ã¤Ã©Ã¹Ã¸Ã Ã¬Ã©Ãº Ã Ã©Ã¯
```

`utf8_encode` on the response did not seem to help.

What should I do to decode correctly ?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I did notice right now that the actual page that shows the data has an encoding of `ISO-8859-1`, but looking in the specific header of the response with the data I see the charset is set to `windows-1255`.

WHat I did now is setting the header to :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255');
```

and on the php's side I added `iconv` and simply **echo**:
        **`echo iconv("WINDOWS-1255","UTF-8",$response);`**

Comment: You cannot be receiving hebrew text encoded in ISO-8859-1, because that character set does not support hebrew.

Comment: it's weird, as the html page-info on Firefox shows the page has that encoding:ISO-8859-1. But when I check the header of the specific response I get windows-1255

Comment: @Ted: What you do now, you have not shared if it solved your issue or not.

Comment: No. I don't know what to do, I keep getting garbage

Comment: @Ted: From your question it's not clear from where you get `$response` and which encoding it actually has. You need to share more code otherwise this is just guessing. E.g. it also looks like the WINDOWS-1252 representation is actually UTF-8 encoded. More code should make it more clear.

Comment: @Hakre Which code? The response I am getting from the site is this:îéãò ìî÷áì  áæ÷ äçáøä äéùøàìéú  àéï. I showed the header and the iconv I was trying to do to convert to UTF-8, but no success. Would you like to see the original page ?

Comment: @$response: `$response` is magically filled with some data out of nowhere?

Comment: I am simply using some parsing on that page: https://www.misim.gov.il/gmrepishur/ if you click on the top right radio button, then on the next page, fill the captcha, then fill this number: 557448412 you should get what I am getting

Comment: That's why I am so interested to know how you guys converted so easily....

Comment: Ah [that business verification website](https://www.misim.gov.il/gmrepishur/) you need to grab the content from. Looks like they do not properly set their headers, let me check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head in the wall for a while, I decided to be straightforward about it and created a mapping for the characters which worked very easily. I couldn't find a solution otherwise.

Here's the code:

```
$lat = array('à','á','â','ã','ä','å','æ','ç','è','é','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ð','ñ','ò','ó','ô','õ','ö','÷','ø','ù','ú');
$heb = array('א','ב','ג','ד','ה','ו','ז','ח','ט','י','ך','כ','ל','ם','מ','ן','נ','ס','ע','ף','פ','ץ','צ','ק','ר','ש','ת');
echo str_replace($lat, $heb, $response);
```

I also found these resources valuable:

```
http://orwell.ru/test/CP/_?cp1252
http://orwell.ru/test/CP/_?cp1255
```

and this one too:

```
http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php
```

Answer (score 2):

The response is not ISO-8859-1 encoded but probably windows-1255 encoded; interpreted that way, the bytes are מידע למקבל  בזק החברה הישראלית  אין. So try converting from windows-1255 to utf-8.

Comment: IMHO ISO-8859-8 is a more likely encoding that windows-1255.

Comment: @Jon: ISO-8859-8 does not contain all characters given in the question.

Comment: @hakre: My bad, didn't check.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela, May I ask how did you convert it ?

Comment: How do you suggest I do the conversion? In my Ajax page's header ? or should I run a conversion function on the Ajax page, and which ?

Answer (score 2):

The string you give in your question

```
îéãò ìî÷áì  áæ÷ äçáøä äéùøàìéú  àéï
```

Looks like the Windows 1252 (Latin I) representation of the Windows 1255 (Hebrew) codepage:

```
EE Windows 1252 î Windows 1255 מ - HEBREW LETTER MEM
E9 Windows 1252 é Windows 1255 י - HEBREW LETTER YOD
E3 Windows 1252 ã Windows 1255 ד - HEBREW LETTER DALET
F2 Windows 1252 ò Windows 1255 ע - HEBREW LETTER AYIN
20 Windows 1252   Windows 1255   - SPACE
EC Windows 1252 ì Windows 1255 ל - HEBREW LETTER LAMED
EE Windows 1252 î Windows 1255 מ - HEBREW LETTER MEM
F7 Windows 1252 ÷ Windows 1255 ק - HEBREW LETTER QOF
E1 Windows 1252 á Windows 1255 ב - HEBREW LETTER BET
EC Windows 1252 ì Windows 1255 ל - HEBREW LETTER LAMED
20 Windows 1252   Windows 1255   - SPACE
20 Windows 1252   Windows 1255   - SPACE
E1 Windows 1252 á Windows 1255 ב - HEBREW LETTER BET
E6 Windows 1252 æ Windows 1255 ז - HEBREW LETTER ZAYIN
F7 Windows 1252 ÷ Windows 1255 ק - HEBREW LETTER QOF
20 Windows 1252   Windows 1255   - SPACE
E4 Windows 1252 ä Windows 1255 ה - HEBREW LETTER HE
E7 Windows 1252 ç Windows 1255 ח - HEBREW LETTER HET
E1 Windows 1252 á Windows 1255 ב - HEBREW LETTER BET
F8 Windows 1252 ø Windows 1255 ר - HEBREW LETTER RESH
E4 Windows 1252 ä Windows 1255 ה - HEBREW LETTER HE
20 Windows 1252   Windows 1255   - SPACE
E4 Windows 1252 ä Windows 1255 ה - HEBREW LETTER HE
E9 Windows 1252 é Windows 1255 י - HEBREW LETTER YOD
F9 Windows 1252 ù Windows 1255 ש - HEBREW LETTER SHIN
F8 Windows 1252 ø Windows 1255 ר - HEBREW LETTER RESH
E0 Windows 1252 à Windows 1255 א - HEBREW LETTER ALEF
EC Windows 1252 ì Windows 1255 ל - HEBREW LETTER LAMED
E9 Windows 1252 é Windows 1255 י - HEBREW LETTER YOD
FA Windows 1252 ú Windows 1255 ת - HEBREW LETTER TAV
20 Windows 1252   Windows 1255   - SPACE
20 Windows 1252   Windows 1255   - SPACE
E0 Windows 1252 à Windows 1255 א - HEBREW LETTER ALEF
E9 Windows 1252 é Windows 1255 י - HEBREW LETTER YOD
EF Windows 1252 ï Windows 1255 ן - HEBREW LETTER FINAL NUN
```

To convert that character set to UTF-8 you need to use a library that does this (e.g. [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) or [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding)) or do it by yourself.

Comment: By comparing your input against a set of common codepages. Have you figured out how to do the conversion?

Comment: Where do you get garbage? You should add some code to your question so  it's more clear where and how you process the input. And keep in mind that your output should be UTF-8 (not ISO-8859-1) otherwise the browser will always show some "garbage" (actually for the browser it's not garbage, it's just that it displays the page as intended, so it's your job to tell the browser how the output should be displayed).

Comment: I am very curious how you and @Jukka K. Korpela got the result so fast :)

Comment: For Jukka, I suggest you visit his homepage, it has some wonderful well written information about characters and encodings. For myself, I've got a bunch of tools on my harddisk to do this stuff.

Comment: I also get this now after using iconvײ³ֲ®ײ³ֲ©ײ³ֲ£ײ³ֲ² ײ³ֲ¬ײ³ֲ®ײ³ֲ·ײ³ֲ¡ײ³ֲ¬  ײ³ֲ¡ײ³ֲ¦ײ³ֲ· ײ³ג‚×ײ³ֲ§ײ³ֲ¡ײ³ֲ¸ײ³ג‚× ײ³ג‚×ײ³ֲ©ײ³ֲ¹ײ³ֲ¸ײ³ֲ ײ³ֲ¬ײ³ֲ©ײ³ֳ·    ײ³ֲ ײ³ֲ©ײ³ֲ¯

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10743/discussion-between-ted-and-hakre)

Answer (score -1):

Compile PHP with `'--enable-zend-multibyte'`.
then please try this

```
mb_convert_encoding("FOO","UTF-8","ISO-8859-1");
```

If you only need to convert.