# converting ajax response from windows-1255 to UTF8

Tags: php, ajax, character-encoding

I use an Ajax call to receive a response in hebrew. The results come from a different site and are `windows-1255` encoded. My page is `UTF-8`.
the response looks like this:

```
îéãò ìî÷áì  áæ÷ äçáøä äéùøàìéú  àéï
```

I found this website: http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php
using windows-1255 to UTF-8 (+mark the last checkbox) and the result is perfect.
Question is how do I do that on PHP ?

Everything I do results in garbage.

```
$data = 'îéãò ìî÷áì  áæ÷ äçáøä äéùøàìéú àéï  ';
echo mb_detect_encoding($data);
```

results in `UTF-8` (maybe it really is UTF-8, as my php file is utf-8)

**I actually need this result:**

```
מידע למקבל  בזק החברה הישראלית אין
```

If I try iconv:

```
echo iconv("WINDOWS-1255", "UTF-8", "îéãò ìî÷áì  áæ÷ äçáøä äéùøàìéú àéï  ");
```

I get this:

```
ֳ®ֳ©ֳ£ֳ² ֳ¬ֳ®ֳ·ֳ¡ֳ¬ ֳ¡ֳ¦ֳ· ֳ₪ֳ§ֳ¡ֳ¸ֳ₪ ֳ₪ֳ©ֳ¹ֳ¸ֳ ֳ¬ֳ©ֳ÷ ֳ ֳ©ֳ¯
```

What is going on? How can I get the hebrew result?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm confused. Do you use Ajax (i.e., XMLHTTPRequest from client side JavaScript) or PHP to get that page? Could you show the PHP code you currently use?

Comment: I use jQuery $.get to call a php page, which in turn is using cURL to bring data from another page that is using the windows-1255 encoding

Comment: So the Ajax part is pretty irrelevant for the time being. Please show your `curl` code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting ajax response from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397344/converting-ajax-response-from-iso-8859-1-to-utf8) - Ted, please don't duplicate questions, instead improve the earlier question.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a file with this contents:

```
echo iconv("WINDOWS-1255", "UTF-8", "îéãò ìî÷áì  áæ÷ äçáøä äéùøàìéú àéï  ");
```

it is very important in which encoding you save the file itself. PHP's strings don't care about encoding, they just work as byte arrays. So if you save such file using UTF-8 encoding, the string will of course be saved in UTF-8 and iconv cannot convert it from WIN1255, because it's in UTF-8.

My suggestion is to 1) retrieve the string in its original encoding from the server 2) save it to a file just as it was 3) experiment using that file, because that way you are sure you only work on the data as it was. Once you try to copy&paste it somewhere, you will probably change the encoding of the thing.

Also viewing the data with a hex editor is not a bad idea, that way you can see for sure what is stored in a file.

Anyway, what you say do try to do seems correct: Get the WIN-1255 data from the server, then call iconv(...) on it, now it's in UTF-8, output it to a HTML page (which of course has a `<meta>` indicating it's in UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

Re-encoding may not be necessary. You could simply serve the same content with a declared encoding of win-1255 and let the browser take care of it.

If you want to reencode, you need to do it on the server like so:

1. Fetch string from remote server.
2. Determine encoding of string (from http headers or html headers).
3. Convert encoding to utf-8 if necessary.
4. Return new values to client with proper utf-8 encoding declaration.

You may be missing the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf8` header in step 4, which would be why your `echo iconv(...)` looks wrong.

Here's a sample function that could do steps 1-3 for you in the common case:

```php
function getUrlAsUtf8($url) {
    $s = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($s) {
        $contenttype = preg_grep('/content-type:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]+)*+((?:(?:(?:\r\n)[ \t]+)|[ \t\x20-\x7e\x80-\xff])*)/i', $http_response_header);
        $inputcharset = null;
        foreach ($contenttype as $ct) {
            if (preg_match('/charset\s*=\s*(.*?)(?:$|;)/i', $ct, $matches)) {
                $inputcharset = strtolower($matches[1]);
            }
        }
        if ($inputcharset and $inputcharset!=='utf-8') {
            $s = mb_convert_encoding($s, 'utf-8', $inputcharset);
        }
    }
    return $s;
}

echo getUrlAsUtf8('http://example.org');
```